# NGRX - When reset the state, selectors returns the value before reset

Tags: angular, ngrx

When I reset the status with a metaReducer, when I access my main page again, the data that shows me using selectors, are those that were before the reset, does anyone know how to fix it? Since I tried many different things and the result is the same

MetaReducer:

```
import { ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { UserActionTypes } from '../../actions/actionTypes';
import { AppState } from '../../models/state';

export function clearStateReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<AppState>): ActionReducer<AppState> {
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === UserActionTypes.Logout) {
      state = undefined;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
```

Selector:

```
import { AppState } from '../../models/state/app-state.model';
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

const getCurrentDate = (state: AppState) => state.date.currentDate;

export const getCurrentDateSelector = createSelector(
  getCurrentDate,
  (currentDate: Date) => currentDate
);
```

For example, when I log in again, it should show me the current date, not the one I had previously selected in a datepicker and saved in the store, since when the reset is done, the date is the current one.

Comment: Why dont you update your state in reducer ?

Comment: The best way to reset the entire state is in a metareducer no?

Comment: No you should reset a state in feature reducer

Comment: Can you show me an example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see it here https://github.com/ngohungphuc/Presentation/blob/master/NgRx/ngrx-demo-v2/src/app/post/store/reducers/post.reducer.ts

Comment: But i need this behavior in multiple reducers